# Golang BUN ORM can't parse where clause

Tags: go, orm

Why instead of the sign? the number doesn't appear?

```
type UserBun struct {
    bun.BaseModel `bun:"table:users,alias:u"`
    ID         int64 `bun:"id"`
}
    
query := db.NewSelect().Model(&UserBun{}).Where("id = ?", 1).String()

fmt.Println(query) 
// result: SELECT "u"."id", "u"."employee_id" FROM "users" AS "u" WHERE (id = ?)
// expected: SELECT "u"."id", "u"."employee_id" FROM "users" AS "u" WHERE (id = 1)
```

Comment: Hello, at a first glance your code looks correct. Only difference from the documentation that I can see is that they use `new` to create a `User`:
```go
user := new(User)
```
```go
err := db.NewSelect().Model(user).Where("id = ?", 1).Scan(ctx)
```

The other thing is that `?` is a [placeholder](https://bun.uptrace.dev/guide/placeholders.html#introduction), and I am not sure it gets replaced with an actual value before using `Scan()`, since I couldn't find this information in the docs.